# Jquery nextuntil select radios

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup (this is an example there are hundreds)

```
<div class="Q3"> 1. Suspension & Chassis <span id='q6_p01'>2</span></div>

      <input type="radio" name="r6_p01" id="r6_p01_1" value="1"/>
      <input type="radio" name="r6_p01" id="r6_p01_2" value="2"/>

<div class="Q3"> 2. Suspension & Chassis <span id='q6_p01'>2</span></div>
```

And I want to find out how many radio buttons I have from one div to the next.

I have tried:

```
var selection = $("div.q3:eq(0)").nextUntil('div','input[type="radio"]').length;
```

And endless variations on that theme, but I always get an answer of 0.

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is `Q3` but your selector is lowercase `q3`.  Otherwise your nextUntil should work.

```
var selection = $("div.Q3:eq(0)").nextUntil('div','input[type="radio"]').length;
```

Comment: I nearly screamed when I saw your reply!  I had been staring at it for an hour.  I changed it though and it still says 0.

Comment: There must be something else happening because when I stripped it right down it does work.  Thanks for the answer.